# How to switch android device to MTP mode programmatically?

Tags: android, usb, mtp, usb-mass-storage

I have android device and it shows "connected as installer" when connected to PC/Mac USB.  I can switch it to "MTP" manually in android settings. I need my app to switch it as MTP (not USB Mass Storage) programmatically when connected, how can i do it?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I doubt there's a supported way to do this (as this mechanism is a potential security feature, e.g. to keep out rogue chargers). You probably need to go through the Android source code to see how they do it, then try to implement this in your app. Not all of this is necessarily exposed through public APIs, and Android may even have mechanisms to block apps from accessing the feature.

Comment: @user149408 correct answer

Comment: @user149408 do u know a way to just detect the current mode? I mean if it is charging only, mtp, ptp, ...etc. If u know please answer this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69832482/detect-programmatically-the-type-of-usb-connection-in-android