# Detect programmatically the type of USB connection in Android

Tags: android

Is it possible to detect the type of the usb connection programmatically whether if it is charging only, MTP, PTP, etc.

I know how to detect if it is connected or not, almost every thread out there is talking about that. I tried finding some Intent event to register a receiver for but I could not find any suitable one.

Note: I don't want to change it programmatically, this is not allowed I guess after Android 6, I just want to encourage the user to do so after detecting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, if you want to receive a device connection event to a computer in mtp mode, you can use this

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    intent?.apply {
        if (action == "android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE") {
            extras?.apply {
                if (getBoolean("connected") && getBoolean("mtp")) {
                // your code here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

More information can be found here
https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.java;l=70;drc=a4812d3c587a10bd9f4b76a26b174df92ee8abb6

Comment: tbh, this question has been asked in a wrong way, the app I am working on depends on AndroidOpenAccessory. Sometimes the connection between the computer and the phone is not perfect which drives me to ask the users to change the usb connection type which automatically triggers the AOA connection, what is ur opinion on that?

Also what do u recommend if I want to have a wired connection between the phone and the mac computer? @Altair08111994